# How to drawing a shapes in QtextEdit

Tags: qt, drawing, qtextedit

I currently working on a text editor using Qtextedit and I want to Draw a shapes like triangle, square and ellipse… etc in the editor to Richness the document.
 So I was wondering if is it possible to do this with Qtextedit and only Qtextedit.
 Actually I am new to Qt so any ideas any tutorial any links would be highly appreciated 
 Thanks in advance and sorry for my english.

Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible, if I understand you correctly. All you need is just implement your own TextEdit derived from `QTextEdit` and reimplement [paintEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#paintEvent)

For example:

**QMyTextEdit.h**

```
class QMyTextEdit : public QTextEdit
{
public:
    QMyTextEdit(QWidget *parent = 0);

protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent * event);
};
```

**QMyTextEdit.cpp**

```
QMyTextEdit::QMyTextEdit(QWidget *parent) :
    QTextEdit(parent)
{
}

void QMyTextEdit::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QTextEdit::paintEvent(event);
    QPainter painter(viewport());
    QPen pen;
    pen.setColor(Qt::blue);
    pen.setWidth(2);
    painter.setPen(pen);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, true);
    QPoint center = viewport()->rect().center();
    painter.drawRect(center.x() - 10,center.y() - 10,20,20);
}
```